# How does Export work when no extension is specified?

Tags: export

I'm looking at someone else's piece of code:

```
Monitor[
  cnt = 1;
  Table[Export[ToString[cnt++],
    Show[orig, 
     ViewAngle -> (ViewAngle /. Options[orig])/(sectionsWide),
     ViewCenter -> {{1, 1, 1}/2, ImageScaled[{y, x}]}], "PNG", 
    Background -> None, ImageSize -> sectionSize {1, 1}],
   {x, 1 - sectionsWide/2, sectionsWide/2, 1}, {y, sectionsWide/2, 
    1 - sectionsWide/2, -1}],
  cnt];
```

In the third line, it appears to be exporting to strings named "1", "2", "3", etc. I checked `Directory[]` and see no such files. Nor in the notebook's directory.

The next piece of code attempts to assemble the results:

```
cnt = 1; exp = 
 ImageAssemble[
  Table[ImageTake[
    Import[ToString[cnt++], "PNG"], {1, sectionSize - 1}, {1, 
     sectionSize - 1}],
   {x, 1 - sectionsWide/2, sectionsWide/2, 1}, {y, sectionsWide/2, 
    1 - sectionsWide/2, -1}]]
```

So my guess is that exporting without an extension exports to virtual files. But I'm unable to find relevant information in [the documentation for `Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).

Comment: make the names like `"SCRATCH"<>ToString[cnt++]` to be easier to search for.

Answer (score 2):

The file extension has nothing to do with the file contents.  It is merely a *convention* that a PNG file has a `.png` extension.  You can give it any extension. You can rename an existing file to anything, including any extension you can think of, without changing its contents.

If you use

```
Export["file", data, "PNG"]
```

it will export in PNG format to a file named `file`. It uses the format specified in the third argument.

Comment: Ah, then there is another reason the files aren't exporting. Odd, I don't see any errors or message. I'll poke around. Thank you.